# Stop reboot after installing SQL Server Express 2008 R2 SP2

Tags: wix, sql-server-2008r2-express

We have a Wix Customer Bootstrapper which installs SQL Server Express 2008 R2 SP2 as an ExePackage.

```
<ExePackage Name="Prerequisites.SQLServer\Prerequisites.SQLServer_setup.exe"
                  SourceFile="$(var.Prerequisites.SQLServer.TargetDir)\setup.exe"
                  DetectCondition="SQLServerVersion &gt;=v10.50.4000.0 OR SQLServerx64Version &gt;=v10.50.4000.0"
                  InstallCondition="INSTALL_SQL_SERVER &gt; 0" 
                  Vital="yes"
                  Permanent="yes">
        <!--WindowsInstaller4_5-->
        <PayloadGroupRef Id="WindowsInstaller4_5_Group"/>

        <Payload Name="Prerequisites.SQLServer\Prerequisites.SQLServer.msi" SourceFile="$(var.Prerequisites.SQLServer.TargetDir)\Prerequisites.SQLServer.msi"/>
        <Payload Name="Prerequisites.SQLServer\SqlExpress2008R2SP2\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe" SourceFile="$(var.Prerequisites.SQLServer.TargetDir)\SqlExpress2008R2SP2\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe" SuppressSignatureVerification="yes" />
        <Payload Name="Prerequisites.SQLServer\SqlExpress2008R2SP2\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe" SourceFile="$(var.Prerequisites.SQLServer.TargetDir)\SqlExpress2008R2SP2\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe" SuppressSignatureVerification="yes" />

      </ExePackage>
```

The `Prerequisites.SQLServer.msi` has the bootstrapper package which has the command line argument `/skiprules=RebootRequiredCheck`. Irrespective of this setting Windows 7 and 8 systems try to reboot. The problem is that the reboot happens and the custom bootstrapper is unable to continue.

I see two options here:

1. Stop the reboot
2. Ensure that custom bootstrapper can continue

Is there another option? Why was this issue not seen in SP1?

How can the reboot be stopped?

How can one ensure that the custom bootstrapper continues?

Comment: /skiprules=RebootRequiredCheck doesn't stop a reboot it stops the SQL install checking whether there is a pending reboot when the install starts - it there is the normal behaviour is to abort the SQL install.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - Neil. Is there a way to stop the reboot or ensure that the bootstrapper continues?

Comment: Can you see what is causing the reboot from the logs, is it definately SQL? You could try adding <ExitCode Value="3010" Behavior="scheduleReboot" /> to your ExePackage.

Comment: We switched back to original SQL Server Express installer and decide not to pursue the SP2 way.